# кириллица из запроса mysqli выводится знаками вопроса

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, mysqli, utf-8

Попробовал все способы изменения кодировки.

Отображение на сайте.

[image: отображение на сайте]

Кодировка строки.

[image: кодировка строки]

Кодировка таблицы.

[image: кодировка таблицы]

head страниц.

[image: head страниц]

Кодировка файла.

[image: кодировка файла]

Текст ломается уже в этом echo после запроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное осталось ещё set charset для коннекта сделать)) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php в теории

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса